# GPars with Groovy, when is explicit synchronization required with collectParallel()?

Tags: multithreading, collections, groovy, synchronization, gpars

Assume the following parallel process in Groovy/Gpars....

```
def result
GParsPool.withPool(5){ 
   result = idList.collectParallel{processItem(it)}
}
```

If `result` is just an array list, and, assuming no thread accesses or manipulates `result` in `processItem()`, does `result` need to be explicitly synchronized? I need to know if I should be doing this instead...

```
def result = Collections.synchronizedList( new ArrayList())
GParsPool.withPool(5){ 
   result = idList.collectParallel{processItem(it)}
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would be surprised if the result being returned is a `List`, but if you look at this comment:

> Iterates over a collection/object with the *collect()* method using an asynchronous variant of the supplied closure to evaluate each collection's element.
>   After this method returns, all the closures have been finished and the caller can safely use the result.
>   It's important to protect any shared resources used by the supplied closure from race conditions caused by multi-threaded access.
>   If any of the collection's elements causes the closure to throw an exception, the exception is re-thrown.

here:
http://code.google.com/p/gparallelizer/source/browse/trunk/src/main/groovy/groovyx/gpars/Parallel.groovy?r=1138

it appears that when everything is done you can safely use the result, without having to have it synchronized.

Comment: I read that too, but wanted to make sure, as I said, `result` is never manipulated in my processing function, so I think I'm good to go! thx